# (JAVA) Need assistance on creating this multiplication table

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

The current code I have is outputting an incorrect format of my intended multiplication table. It outputs the current table :
[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println();
        int[][] smallTable = createMultiplicationTable(3);
        printMultiplicationTable(smallTable);
        
        System.out.println();
        int[][] largeTable = createMultiplicationTable(10);
        printMultiplicationTable(largeTable);
        
    }
    
    //Create and return a multiplication table witn n rows and n columns
    public static int[][] createMultiplicationTable(int n) {
        int max = n;
        int[][]table = new int[max][max];
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < max; j++) {
                table[i][j] = i * j;
            }
        }
        return table;
        
        
        
    }
    
    //Print multiplication table using %4d to print each value
    public static void printMultiplicationTable(int[][] table) {
        int max = table.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

The correct format is suppose to look as so:
[image]

Where in my code am I creating an error?

Comment: So the problem is the first row and column only containing `0`? Where do you think these values come from?

Comment: I believe these values are coming from an incorrect use of my second method. Just not clear as to where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare an `int` array as you did here:

```
int[][]table = new int[max][max];
```

all elements have a default/initial value of zero and since you only assign values to indices i,j greater than one in your for loop, the elements with indices 0,i or 0,j remain unchanged. A small change like below should give you the desired result

```
public static int[][] createMultiplicationTable(int n) {
    int max = n;
    int[][]table = new int[max][max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            table[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```